# Do MLB players wear new uniforms every game?

Tags: baseball, mlb, uniform

Do MLB players wear new uniforms every game? Or only when pants or top becomes too dirty or torn. The uniforms always look spotless so I assumed they were new.

Comment: Is laundry really impossible in the USA?

Comment: my mom always had trouble with grass stains so I assumed they could be pretty tough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is basically **No**, though there is no official statement of teams many articles I have read so far points out teams does not provide new jerseys to the players for every game. *Uniforms are washed, mended and pressed to look as new every game*.

From a [article of CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/LIVING/03/31/baseball.open.uniforms/index.html):

> Mitch Poole, clubhouse manager for the Los Angeles Dodgers "uniforms used to be scrubbed until the fabric resembled fur. But now they use an industrial stain remover specifically made for Major League called Slide Out".

[Factory on Columbus Avenue](https://yanksgoyard.com/2017/01/07/yankees-uniform-history/) in New Rochelle (NY), the Raleigh Athletic Equipment Company is where uniforms of the New York Yankees are washed, mended and pressed.

An [article on Erica Ford](http://www.latimes.com/sports/la-sp-seamstress12-2008may12-story.html), the official seamstress for the Los Angeles Angels of Anaheim baseball team will further helps in clarifying things.